# How to create ListView disabled item labels for sections of list items?

Tags: android, database, listview

I have a customized `Cursor` based adapter for my `ListView`.  Each `Cursor` has a few columns of data, sorted by the priority column.

I know you can create a disabled list item to act as a sort of header, like in the Market app (the little green labels).

What I would like to do is display a header for each group of items with a different priority.  They are already sorted by priority.

Example data:

```
title, priority
note1, high
note3, high
note2, low
note4, low
```

Example of what I want in `ListView`:

```
===High Priority====
-note1
-note3
===Low Priority=====
-note2
-note4
```

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List5.html - How they do it in the official apidemo

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Cursors you can try my [SectionCursorAdapter](https://github.com/monxalo/android-section-adapter).

See the source for an example how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Having heading rows in a `ListView` is a matter of custom-crafting an appropriate `ListAdapter`. Have `areAllItemsEnabled()` return `false` and implement `isItemEnabled()` as needed.

Where things get tricky is in your chosen data model. Your `ListAdapter` will need to return `6` from `getCount()`, since you want six rows in your list. Your underlying data has four rows. That means you are going to have to write a fair bit of code to translate positions from what the `ListView` thinks (6) to what your data thinks (4), and handling the header rows for the other two positions.

Comment: Is there a data model I could use that would work better? Maybe build a second data model between the cursor and the adapter?

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile: The only way I have done headings so far is where I have individual Cursors -- in your case, one Cursor for high and one Cursor for low. See this sample project: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView/Sections/  If your number of priorities is fairly low, you could use the same technique, but if you are seeking a lot of headings, it is probably more efficient to cook up an adapter that can work with your existing data model.